# Write own function to convert decimal numbers to binary

Tags: php, numbers

I am trying to write my own function to convert decimal numbers to binary. I know there are build-in functions for this, but I'm trying to write my own here, which I can't get to work correctly.

Right now the code below doesn't give me any output. I'm new to PHP so ever hint where I went wrong would help.

Code:

```
<?php

    {

    $dec = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['num'])) {
        $dec = $_POST['num'];
    }

    decimal_binary($dec);
    echo $dec;

    }

function decimal_binary($dec) 
{

    $rem;
    $i = 1;
    $binary = 0;
    while ($dec != 0)
    {
        $rem = $dec % 2;
        $dec /= 2;
        $binary += $rem * i;
        $i *= 10;
    }

    $dec = $binary;
    echo $binary;

    return decimal_binary($dec);

}


?>
<html> 
    <body>

    <form action="3.php" method="POST">
        Integer <input type="number" name="num">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Infinite recursion: `return decimal_binary($dec);`

Comment: in other words, turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors`, and you'd see the program bomb out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made an infinite recursion, I mean you are calling the function over and over again with the result as parameter.

**- EDIT -**

So your function doesn't work, but I came up with this one, and it does work. Try it out:

```
function decimal_binary($dec){
    $binary;
    while($dec >= 1){
        $rem = $dec % 2;
        $dec /= 2;
        $binary = $rem.$binary;
    }
    if($binary == null){
        $binary = 0;
    }
    return $binary;
}
```

**- END EDIT -**

Also, you need to place the function before you call it, and when you call it, you need to assign it to a variable so that you can use the output value in other parts of your code:

```
<?php

// function here

$dec = 0;
if(isset($_POST['num'])){
    $dec = $_POST['num'];
}

$bin = decimal_binary($dec);
?>
```

Comment: Will also need to change the call to this function so you pick up the returned value somewhere something like `$bin = decimal_binary($dec)`

Comment: I just saw the questions was edited or I didn't see the code above, but yes, I am editing the answer...

Comment: <!--// $dec=$binary; <-- no need to assign if you'll output it.
    // echo $binary; <-- I don't see this necessary.-->
i did this to know if my echo would work with in the function without returning it. but it didnot. so i must have missed someting.

Comment: @ProblematicSolution I see, well, to be honest I didn't even check if the function works, I only checked the obvious syntax. Did you copy the code exactly as I wrote it? I tried it on my server and it returns `0` with decimal `24567.15`. Take a look at https://www.snowlinks.net/binary.php

Comment: @ProblematicSolution By the way, your echo **should work fine**. But it will output it at the spot where that php script is... let's say it's at the top of the file, it will be even before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @ProblematicSolution turns out your function doesn't work logically, the `$binary` variable will always return `NaN`. Let me think of a way to make it work and if I find a function that works, I'll edit it here and in my site.

Comment: @ProblematicSolution I am glad it worked! Please mark my answer as the solution so that other people can benefit from it too!